# Filter Array of objects into seperate lists

Tags: javascript, arrays

So to give an example = >

> Object:
>
> WachtRegistratieID: (...)
> Name: (...)
> StartDateTime: (...)
> StopDateTime: (...)
> PersonName: (...)
> Description: (...)
> Phone1: (...)
> Phone2: (...)
> Phone3: (...)
> Phone4: (...)
> Phone5: (...)
> Phone6: (...)

This is 1 object, What I'm trying to do is this =>
in an array, I can have separate objects with the same name, but all the rest are different date, now I want to split 1 big array into separate arrays for those who have the same name, something like this =>

`Array[[Object{Name=first},Object{Name=first}],[Object{Name=second},Object{Name=second}]]`
how i'm currently trying to it is like this =>

```js
    export function CompileList(list) {
      let compiledList = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (i === 0) {
          compiledList.push([list[i]]);
        }
        for (let j = 0; j < compiledList; j++) {
          console.log(compiledList[j][0].Name + " and this other " + list[i].Name);
          if (compiledList[j][0].Name == list[i].Name) {
            compiledList[j].push = list[i];
          } else {
            compiledList.push(list[i]);
          }
        }
      }
      return compiledList;
    }
```

the output of this is correct, but the problem is here for every name there is an extra array made like this =>

`Array[[Object{Name=first},Object{Name=first}],[Object{Name=first},Object{Name=first}]]` because I have two times the same name...

sorry if this is a duplicate question or if it is not clear what I mean, let me know

Comment: What is `compiledList[j].push = list[i];` supposed to do?

Comment: [How to group an array of objects by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-to-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key)

Comment: @Andreas this splits the list into seperate arrays per name

Comment: You talk about the mentioned duplicate? If so, then just call `Object.values()` on the resulting grouped object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are looking for grouping array of objects by key, I made a small snippet for you.

```js
const list = [
{name: "abc", "phone1": 12345678, "phone2": 98789656}, 
{name: "def", "phone1": 34567098, "phone2": 12345667},
{name: "abc", "phone1": 234567098,"phone2": 124455667},

]

var compiledList = list.reduce((acc, x) =>  {   
  if(!acc[x.name]) {
    acc[x.name] = []
  }
  acc[x.name].push(x);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(compiledList);
```